# How simple is too simple for a (nested) class?

Tags: java, oop, conventions

I am new to OOP, and still trying to wrap my head around just how encapsulated things should be. **This question is about best practices, NOT about how to achieve functionality**.

For an assignment, we are asked to make linked lists whose nodes contain two Strings: the name of the person spreading a disease, and the name of the person becoming infected. Each case of infection is only a record of who is involved, an infection doesn't actually *do* anything.

The assignment description suggests we add the two names as fields to the Nodes of the linked list. But my fledgling OOP-radar is booping, and I am unsure of whether or not I should instead create a nested Infection class within the node, or a top-level class of its own, which stores the two Strings.

So my internal conflict (and question) here is: at what point does an object become too simple to merit being an object anymore, while still keeping within the OOP-paradigm? Should I create an Infection class, or add data to the Node to keep it simple?

Comment: In this case, the `LinkedList` should not care what types it holds - it should be _generic_. The node should have some generic type, and hold objects of that type. Your two attributes then naturally fall into an object, which can be contained in your shiny new generic `List`.

Comment: A real, generic, reusable linked list should in fact not expose its internals (the Node class), and should accept any kind of object. That what the standard java.util.LinkedList does. Good OOP practices would recommend not creating your own linked list, and reuse the one that already exists and has been tested over and over. But this is an assignment, where the linked list is not supposed to be reusable, so it doesn't matter much. I would still separate the data referenced by the node from the internals of the node (i.e. the next and previous references), and thus introduce an Infection class.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about complexity of an Object. I mean an object can be as complicated as an entire class or as simple as holding 2 Strings. As long as it fits its pupose...

Comment: Thanks for your helpful responses everyone. Looks like I need to learn a little about generics!

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it the same way as Collections API does it: **Create generic data structures that can hold any kind of objects and let the objects to define their internal structure/functionality.**

The type could be generified, that would be the best practice.